# NPM Build Issues - Salesforce UX

Tags: node.js, npm, salesforce, npm-install, salesforce-lightning

I am Trying to install https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system
and cant solve the NPM problems i get. 
I am new to node and all the stuff but whily triyn to fix the issu i am getting new ones after 5 hours of trying i wannt to ask you guys, maybe you have some idea.

This are the last lines from the log file

```
4461 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4     
(node_modules\fsevents):
4462 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
4463 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
4463 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
4463 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
4463 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
4464 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
4465 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
4466 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
4466 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
4466 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
4466 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
4467 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\sane\node_modules\fsevents):
4468 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
4469   verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
4469 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
4469  verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
4469 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
4470  warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\fsevents):
4471 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
4472 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
4472 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
4472 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
4472 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
4473 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
4474 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
4475 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
4475 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
4475 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
4475 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
4476 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.5.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
4476 verbose stack Exit status 1
4476 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASOL.Projects\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
4476 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
4476 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
4476 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASOL.Projects\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
4476 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
4476 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
4476 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
4476 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
4477 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.5.2
4478 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\salesforge
4479 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
4480 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ASOL.Projects\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
4481 verbose node v8.10.0
4482 verbose npm  v6.1.0
4483 error code ELIFECYCLE
4484 error errno 1
4485 error node-sass@4.5.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
4485 error Exit status 1
4486 error Failed at the node-sass@4.5.2 postinstall script.
4486 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
4487 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Does it have somthing to do with gyp?